Identical rigid bodies affected differently by the same force
I want to fire multiple cannonballs one after another using rigid bodies. I am trying to achieve that by placing multiple cannonballs at the bottom of the barrel and keeping them in place by keyframing the "Animated" property. The force field is not animated and its strength remains the same. Both cannonball rigid bodies are identical. They are separate objects, not instance duplicates. Yet for some reason the second cannonball is fired with different force compared to the first, as if getting "charged up" by the force, because when I move the "Animated" keyframe closer to frame 0, its ejection velocity drops. Please help.



hello please share your file

Added .blend file

The object affected by the force field will accelerate through time, here it doesn't seem like Blender takes into account the fact that at frame N the rigid body B is not supposed to get the same speed as rigid body A as rigid body B'a Animated option was disabled later. I'm not sure how to solve it, except decreasing the force field Strength value through time? But I may be wrong and I hope someone will know better
